# Proper Inheritance for Spring Configurations

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I am creating a project utilizing the new Spring configurations.  I have a base class which holds a few properties:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Basic.class, Protected.class})
public class BaseTest {
  @Autowired(required = false) protected String userName;
  @Autowired(required = false) protected String password;
  @Autowired protected String baseURL;

  @Test
  public void outputData() {
    System.out.println("UserName: " + userName + " Password: " 
                        + password + "Base URL: " + baseURL);
  }
}

@ActiveProfiles("default,protected")
public abstract class ProtectedTest extends BaseTest
{
  @Autowired protected String userName;
  @Autowired protected String password;
}

@Configuration @Profile("default")
public class Basic {
   @Bean public String baseURL() { return "http://www.baseURL.com"; }
}

@Configuration @Profile("protected")
public class Protected {
   @Bean public String userName() { return "userName"; }
   @Bean public String password() { return "password"; }
}
```

However, when I go to run my protected tests I receive a notification that the base URL is not wired in properly.  Since it extends the BaseTest, and has both profiles active, why am I not receiving the baseURL bean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be `@ActiveProfiles({"default","protected"})`,  in your case it will assume that the profile by name `default, protected` is active, not `default` and `protected`

One more thing is that annotation in base class `BaseTest` is not derived by the `ProtectedTest`, so you will again need to put `@RunWith` and `@ContextConfiguration` for your  test to run

Comment: It had been a long day and I had just copied that from my environment variable configuration.  However there are two things to note here: You don't have to add the RunWith on [extended classes](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/RunWith.html) or the ContextConfigurations [they inherit by default](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html#inheritLocations())